# rspec spec invalid option: --default_path=spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm getting a very strange error from rspec:

```
$ rspec spec

invalid option: --default_path=spec
```

I'm in a rails 4, ruby 2 app and I've updated everything to rspec-rails 3.0.0.beta. I've dumped and re installed rspec, .rspec, and spec_helper.rb.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably using a different version of RSpec. The tests run fine from the balanced-ruby project. Make sure you have this line in the Gemfile:

```
gem "rspec", '~> 2.10'
```

Then run `bundle install` and finally try again with `bundle exec rspec spec`.

Comment: But then if I remove balanced, it is still broken.

Answer (score 0):

This is old but for whomever Googles this: in addition to checking your `Gemfile`, take a look at your repo's `.rspec` config file to see if there is an issue. If that doesn't fix it, check your environment to see if you have a global `.rspec` config file. Try `cat ~/.rspec` to see if you have one and if there are any issues with it. The global config caused issues for me.